# file access in C# program called by PHP

Tags: c#, php, file, permissions

This is the context: I've got to write a source for an intranet site which allows users to import a csv file into MySQL database.

This import is very massive that's why I wrote a C# program.

This program creates some thread which reads some lines of my csv file.

These thread control, change type and insert my data into MySQL database with SQL like this:

```
insert into table1 (fields) values (dataline 1 ), (data line 25),...,(data line n);
```

This request exists for 9 tables.

This program can be used by everyone because the source code is dynamic : example to insert data I write a dictionary which contain my 9 tables with all fields, types and  the CSV header of the import file (which contains some accent and symbol, I've to change it because I can't put them into fieldname in my database).

This dictionary can be create only with a file called MAP.csv

Example:

```
table   /   field     /    type  /   header

table 1  /  field1_table1 /string  / hêàder

table 1   / field2_table1/ int    /  header1

table 2   / field1_table2/ date   /  hêàder2

table 1  /  field3_table1/ string  / hêàder3
```

My C# program works very well when I execute the program.exe

But when I call it with php with `exec("programpath.exe parameter1 parameter2",return,otherreturn)` function this program can't work.

In fact when I try to access to externfile like config.xml , MAP.csv, otherfile.txt/csv/.. with my c# program. The execution stop and there is a windows error which says "program.exe stop its work" ( `program.exe à cessé de fonctionner` in French).

So I try to write my problem simply: when I try to access into a file with my c# program called by php, there is a window problem which stop the traitment.

EDIT :
I found the solution, I just have to do a cd c:/path_program/
In fact  when I start my website the current folder is not c:/ but the folder in which Symfony starts...
Was just a beginner error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Edit post for the solution

Comment: i would really recommend you to do it within the application --> as in my answer. otherwise if you call the application from somewhere you will have the same problem again...

Comment: i can't do without the application because this an enormous import, so if i do it with a php traitment i need 8 hours to import all lines.

but with my application i just need 1 hour, and when you're on a company, you must take the fastest  solution ^^

Comment: what i mean: i recommend you to handle the relative path within the c# application...

Comment: oh yes i did it
i've any version of my application, one with , and one without :)

Answer (score 0):

Could be a permission problem.

The Webserver is running under a certain security context (user). Depending on the used Webserver (IIS, apache, ...) and its configuration.

As you execute an application out of your PHP it will run under the same "User" as your WebServer.

You said that it seems as your application crashes as soon as an external file gets accessed --> very possible the user which executes the website has access to run the exe but no access for the configuration file.

you use relative paths to access the file:
to map the relative to the application path to an absolute path you can use this snippet:

```
string appPath = System.Windows.Application.ResourceAssembly.Location;
string relativeResourcePath = "RESSOURCES/file.csv";
string absolutePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, relativeResourcePath);
```

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Comment: check my edit, are you using IIS? on what OS / in what Version?

Comment: you mean i've to permit "all" access to my user? so i check the user permission on my httpd.conf in apache :  <Directory />
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/htdocs>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>  but with these parameters it doesn't work (that's default parameters)

Comment: i'm working  with xamp for win32 1.8.0 on windows7  for company system

Comment: is the app.exe + its configuration in the published folder or somewhere else on the disk?

Comment: i try with
C:\www\htdocs\program
C:\www\\***\src\PF\ImportBundle\Resources\doc\exec\program (i'm working with symfony 2 (there is some restriction with symfony2 with the access permission but it should work with the C:\www\htdocs\program))
i try c:\ and other local folder but no onework
i though it was a permission access with apache and my desk but i can't allow apache to work with the desk because xampp is not instal like a service (source says : open "services.msc" on command, search wampp apache on local service, right click, properties and check "allow the service to work with the desk")

Comment: try to get some more information about the error --> put all code which is not working in try catches and log the errors, like that you will see better whats going on.

Comment: Test program:
System.Console.Out.WriteLine("a");//ok
System.Console.Out.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);//ok
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//ok
CsvReader csvMap = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("RESSOURCES/MAP.CSV"), false, ';');//crash
Config.Instance.FilePath = "test";//crash
System.Console.Out.WriteLine(Config.Instance.FilePath);// crash
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//ok
System.Console.Out.WriteLine("z");//ok
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); //ok
CsvReader csvMap = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(Config.Instance.MapFile), false, ';');//crash

Comment: i check with consol error the first problem with the csvreader :
can't found a part of path access c:\www\mywebsite\web\RESSOURCES\MAP.CSV
 that's strange because this line is called by my program c# and this program and all configuration are stock there :C:\www\my website\src\PF\ImportBundle\Resources\doc\exec\program\program\RESSOURCES\MAP.csv , for example, do you know why the path change ?

Comment: you use relative paths... you can use absolute paths (not to recommend) or mask the paths based on the assembly execution path. check the edit...

Comment: i changed my relative path by absolute path but when i execute my program with the exec(),the program launches and when it wants to search a parameter on config or other file, it searches in new path example:'exec("C:/www/***/src/PF/ImportBundle/Resources/doc/exec/ExportMasse/ExportMasse/bin/Debug/program.exe")'
Program's launching 'CsvReader csvMap = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("RESSOURCES/MAP.CSV"), false, ";");'
path file's : "C:/www/***/src/PF/ImportBundle/Resources/doc/exec/ExportMasse/ExportMasse/bin/Debug/RESSOURCES/MAP.CSV"
but it search in "C:/www/***/web/RESSOURCES/MAP.CSV

Comment: i found the solution, check my edit.
Thanks for your help and your time that's really cool